# Who is Petrov of the Petrov-Galerkin method?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ho.history-overview, na.numerical-analysis

I was not able to find the origin of the name *Petrov* in the Petrov-Galerkin method for the numerical approximation of PDEs.

Wikipedia refers to a certain Alexander G. Petrov, but it is still not clear who he was: on the Internet I found two persons called Alexander G. Petrov, both born during the 40's, but I think that the Petrov I am looking for should be born before, since Boris Galerkin lived in 1871-1945.

Can you suggest me any bibliographic resource to consult?

[EDIT: The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method) I was referring to now contains the correct name of Petrov]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Petrov you are looking for is: Georgii Ivanovich Petrov (1912-1987), biographies are [here](http://hit2003.narod.ru/persons/great/petrov/petrov_en.html) and [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/0038-5670/30/10/M11;jsessionid=86AE489FDBD558BBF96612B7300CF9ED.c3) and [here.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0015462812030015#page-2)

I quote from the third biography:

> G.I. Petrov was a prominent Russian scientist in the field of
>   aerodynamics, gasdynamics, and space research. Even his first studies
>   connected with the investigation of viscous laminar flows attracted
>   the attention of the scientific community. In studying these problems
>   Petrov not only was the first who applied the Galerkin method but also
>   inventively advanced it. It was M.V. Keldysh who noted that they
>   greatly advance the research in the field of fluid flow stability and
>   for that reason the Galerkin method is now justly called the
>   Galerkin-Petrov method.

The key reference is:

G. I. Petrov, *Application of the method of Galerkin to a problem involving the stationary flow of a viscous fluid*, Prikl. Matem. Mekh. **4,** 3 (1940).

Answer (score 3):

I've recently found a very interesting [SIAM review article](http://www.unige.ch/~gander/Preprints/Ritz.pdf) [1] regarding the history of the Petrov-Galerkin method. The figure of G.I. Petrov seems to have contributed with a simple, but significant improvement to the Galerkin method:

> In Russia, Petrov [2] proposed to use approximation spaces different from the test spaces, which led to the now-called Petrov–Galerkin family of methods.

I highly suggest the reading of [1], since the history of the Petrov-Galerkin method is particularly thrilling!

---

[1] Gander, M.J., and Wanner, G., "From Euler, Ritz, and Galerkin to Modern Computing", SIAM Review 54.4 (2012), pp. 627-666.

[2] G. I. Petrov, "Application of Galerkin’s method to the problem of stability of flow of a viscous fluid", J. Appl. Math. Mech., 4 (1940), pp. 3–12 (in Russian).